# Interval is homeomorphic to a circumference less a point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $f:\left(-1,1\right)\longrightarrow \Bbb S$ \ $\lbrace-1\rbrace$ be a map defined by $t\mapsto e^{i\pi t}$ where $\Bbb S=\lbrace z\in\Bbb C: \|z\| = 1\rbrace$

Is $f$ an homeomorphism?

I proved that $f$ is continuous function and bijective and  $f^{-1}:\Bbb S$ \ $\lbrace-1\rbrace\longrightarrow\left(-1,1\right)$

it´s

$$f^{-1}\left(z\right)=f^{-1}\left(e^{i\theta}\right)=\frac{\theta}{\pi} \text{ if } \theta\in\left[0,\pi\right) \text{ or } \frac{\theta-2\pi}{\pi} \text{ if } \theta\in \left(\pi,2\pi\right)$$

Can You help me please?

Comment: Is your question that you don't know how to show $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes, I don´t know  if $\theta_{1}\in\left[0,\pi\right)$ and $\theta_{2}\in \left(\pi,2\pi\right)$ why $f$ is conituous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your function is a homeomorphism. As you said, it is continuous and bijective.

To show that the inverse $f^{-1}: \mathbb{S} \to (-1,1)$ is continuous, instead of splitting it up the way you did, it is more clear if you say
$ \mathbb{S}=\{e^{i\theta}\mid -\pi < \theta < \pi \} = \{e^{i\pi t}\mid -1 < t < 1 \}$. Now we can simply note that $f^{-1}(e^{i\pi t}) = t$ is continuous since $t$ a polynomial of degree one and all polynomials are continuous.

Comment: I don´t understand :0

Comment: On the left of answers and questions you can vote up or down, or click on the tick mark to accept the answer. Its how you gain points on this site. :)

Comment: Thank You!! I did Know, I´m new at this :D

Comment: Thanks! You also get points if you ask good questions and people vote up your questions. If your reputation/points go up, people are also more likely to answer your questions, so it benefits everyone to earn reputation.

Comment: If  I want to prove continuity of $f^{-1}$  what do you recommend?

Comment: You can either say the map $e^{i\pi t}\to t$ is continuous since $t$ is a polynomial. Or you can explicitly construct the function $f^{-1}$, but you need to be careful with the domain of $\log$.